# Naming controllers in HMVC pattern using php's namespaces

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller, organization, hmvc

I have multiple libraries created in `application/libraries` for the APIs I use.

APIs:

- Vimeo
- Flickr

Now I have created in `application/modules/apis/controllers/vimeo.php` and `application/modules/apis/controllers/flickr.php` that will interact with the libraries upon request by the other modules.

The problem is that now I redeclare the classes:

- libraries/Flickr.php:

  `Class Flickr { }`
- modules/apis/controllers/flickr.php:

  `Class Flickr extends MX_Controller { }`

So I get in my apache2's error log: `Cannot redeclare class Flickr in ...`

**EDIT:**

So having in my `modules/apis/controllers/flickr.php` file:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

Class Flickr extends MX_Controller { ... }
```

How should I use:

```
namespace controllers\blog

class user extends \CI_Controller {
```

explained here: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/212661/ ?

Tried doing:

```
<?php

//TRIED:
namespace controllers\flickr;
namespace Flickr;
namespace modules\apis\controllers\flickr;

if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

Class Flickr extends \MX_Controller { ... }

$_ns = __NAMESPACE__;
```

But I get no response from a simple function that echoes out 'alex' and no error in my log calling the controller and function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP 5.3 added support for namespaces. CodeIgniter doesn't support them yet though, but I did find a recent forum post that claims to have a patch that will allow you to use them.

http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/212661/

Comment: This seams to be the solution, but can't get it to understand how should I apply it to my problem. How `namespace controllers\blog` `class user extends \CI_Controller {` should be in my case?

Comment: I think you also need to place the line `$_ns = __NAMESPACE__;` at the bottom of your controller file.

Comment: already did, I don't get the error anymore... but calling the function returns nothing

Comment: Too bad this answers contains nothing that answers the question but a deadlink.